# Export Power Point presentations to flash with control buttons on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libreoffice

I need to export `*.pps`, `*.ppt`, `*.ppsx`, and `*.pptx` files to `.swf` files. On Windows I used iSpring for Power Point, and worked well.

This is the result of iSpring:

> [image]

I am searching for an application that is able to export something like this but with the following requirements:

- animations must work
- music must play
- <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Previous</kbd> buttons
- <kbd>Sound</kbd> and <kbd>Fullscreen</kbd> buttons

I tried Libre Office Impress that exports `pps` files to `swf`, but it doesn't offer button support for Next/Previous Slide, Play/Stop.

What do you suggest me?